# Visual Studio - can't find "export template" option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I want to port a Phonegap app to Windows Phone 8. I need to open a Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File in Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Phone 8 and choose File -> Export Template.

However this menu entry doesn't exist. I googled a bit and find I can create a Hotkey pointing to File.ExportTemplate by using Tools -> Options -> Keyboard. But there is no File.ExportTemplate Entry in the List.

Second troubleshoot I found was looking in Tools -> Customize -> Command Tab -> Category "File", but again, no entry for File.ExportTemplate.

**EDIT:**
I should mention I'm running Windows 8 on a virtual Machine, VMWare Player 5.0.0.

**EDIT 2:**
I got myself a trial version Visual Studio 2012 and I can`t find the option there either.

Answer (score 6):

Export Template can be found under the "Project" Category in VS 2017.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the Export template option manually from the Tools->Customize menu.

First choose the location where you want to add the menu item (i.e. File menu):

[image: Customize window]

Locate the Export template option and add it:

[image: Add command window]

Comment: Hmm... File - Export Template... is not available in Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone.

Answer (score 1):

Please let me say you that now Visual Studio 2017 "Export Template..." works fine. You should open the project for template, and then click "Project" > "Export template..." and follow instructions by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this support page](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/529592/missing-export-template-in-file-menu) you might need to reset your settings.

> I have reset the settings to 'Visual Basic Development Settings' which has indeed fixed the problem

If that doesn't work then there may be some condition with the solution you are editing that may be hiding this menu option. Please post more details on the project that you are trying to export from if resetting this doesn't work.

Comment: thank you for your reply, resetting the settings didn´t work. All I can say is it´s not the settings of the solution because opening a new project in VS doesnt show the menu entry either.